# Syntax Error when writing @Html.Raw(Html.Debug) in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i'm trying to combine C# code with javascript in MVC to enable "debug" only when i'm using the page in debug mode.

Here i get an error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Control.init(
            "@(ViewBag.Control)", 
            @Html.Raw(Html.IsDebug() ? "true" : "false")
            );
    });
</script>
```

In the line: @Html.Raw(...)  i get "Syntax error"

Full code:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css/normalize")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css/bootstrap")

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

    @RenderSection("head", false)

</head>
<body>

    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/control")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Control.init(
                "@(ViewBag.Control)", 
                @Html.Raw(Html.IsDebug() ? "true" : "false")
                );
        });
    </script>


    @RenderSection("scripts", false)

</body>
</html>
```

Is debug Method:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace System.Web.Mvc
{
    public static class GUIHelper
    {
        public static bool IsDebug(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        {
#if DEBUG
            return true;
#else
            return false;
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

When i do:

```
"@(Html.IsDebug() ? "true" : "false")"
```

instead of:

```
@(Html.IsDebug() ? "true" : "false")
```

works, but...:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Control.init(
            "Control1", 
            "true" // instead of true
            );
    });
</script>
```

---

*** Update: 2013-11-27 ***

Solution 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Control.init(
            "@(ViewBag.Control)", 
            "@(Html.IsDebug() ? "true" : "false")" == "true"
            );
    });
</script>
```

Solution 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function () {
        @Html.Raw("Control.init("+ViewBag.Control+","+(Html.IsDebug() ? "true" : "false")+")")
    });
</script>
```

Comment: How did you implement IsDebug method?

Comment: Updated, please check

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
@{Html.Raw(Html.IsDebug() ? "true" : "false")}
```

Comment: I'm still having "syntax error"... I have also tried @(Html.IsDebug() ? "true" : "false") but don't work

Comment: Don't work... i don't know why but if i do: the same with "" works... like: "@{Html.Raw(Html.IsDebug() ? "true" : "false");}"... but i don't want '"false"' or '"true"', i want 'false' or 'true'

Comment: you could always put the whole Control.init statemtn into the Html.Raw and use string concat to build the whole statement, that will work

Answer (score 0):

This gives the desired output for me:

```
@(Html.Raw(Html.IsDebug() ? "true" : "false"))
```